# camera is not working? kotlin-QR code scanner

Tags: android, kotlin

I create an interface for QR code reader. It's working but, camera permission doesn't work. I checked the emulator camera too. but there's no problem. I added camera permission to the manifest too. I can't find where's the problem.

**This's the code of QR reader**

[Cannot solve this error? Kotlin (QR Reader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455343/cannot-solve-this-error-kotlin-qr-reader/69455708#69455708)

can you please help me to find if there an error in this code. I solve the previous problem in that question. I'm still learning kotlin.

Emulator AVD manager permission[camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO5h9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue with dexter before, have you tried using activity result contract API? you can check more about that in this article
[Activity Result contract](https://wajahatkarim.com/2020/05/activity-results-api-onactivityresult/)

Comment: Okay I'll try this. Thanks a lot.